# Explore - Nested Data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I stuck with a problem and need your help.

I have an explore (“client_info”), which keeps all information about clients.
As main, i take “client” view and add all additional information to it from other views. I want to bring info from view “Abo”, which in fact has repeated rows.

“Client” view has PK “id_client” + FK “abo_option_id”

“Abo” view has PK “id_abo” + repeated rows with key “id_abo_option” + some attributes, such as “abo_option_price”

Client view

| id_client | abo_option_id |
| --- | --- |
| client_1 | abo_opt_A |
| client_2 | abo_opt_D |

Abo view

| id_abo | option.id_abo_option | option.price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abo_1 | abo_opt_A | 10 |
|  | abo_opt_B | 20 |
| abo_2 | abo_opt_C | 10 |
|  | abo_opt_D | 15 |

As result:

| id_client | abo_option_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| client_1 | abo_opt_A | 10 |
| client_2 | abo_opt_D | 15 |

Indeed i checked the documentation, but what i found is a case, when the join is based on id_abo + unnest on repeated structure (abo__option)

https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/best-practices/how-to-model-nested-bigquery-data-in-looker

The solution for a similar, but easier problem, if the link would be over "id_abo", would be the following:

explore: client_info {
from: client

join: abo {
relationship:one_to_many
sql_on: ${client.id_abo} = ${abo.id_abo} ;;
}

join: abo__option {
relationship: one_to_many
sql: LEFT JOIN UNNEST(${abo.option}) as abo__option ;;
}
}

What could be a solution here?

Best regards,
Sergey